# C# window application

Tags: c#

I am developing c# application, in which this application is act as server.My front end is flex application.when i am testing my application through browser i passed a url as below.

http://serverip:8082/item/detail/2210

As response it was showing not serviced, no valid session.

But when I tried from different machine I got the response back perfectly.

Can any one please tell why it is happening.

Comment: Try http://localhost:8082/item/detail/2210. I suspect it has something to do with [this](http://www.quantumofgeek.com/2010/05/burned-again-by-loopback-checking-in-iis/).

Comment: No, that is not the case i am working .server is running in different machine.so we need to provide the ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a non standard port, you may have to open the firewall to allow eternal address or subnet to access? A good way I usually use to test this is using Telnet

```
telnet.exe serverip serverport
```

Other things could be DNS or Host Headers in IIS

Cheers